# jQuery get list items as text and display them in a confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small confirm that displays data on the page for the user to re-read and to see if he made any mistakes and I have included a list of categories but I can't manage to display them in the confirm
My code is below:

```
            $("#add_campaign").on('submit', function(event){
            if(!confirm("Confirm:\n" +
                
                "\nCategorii selectate: " + categoriesInConfirm() +
                
                "\nContinue?")) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });

    function categoriesInConfirm()
    {
        $('#newCategories li span').each(function (index,value){
             $(value).text())
        })
    }
```

I used the following line in my console to check if I can get the list and it works:

```
$('#newCategories li span').each(function (index,value){console.log($(value).text())})
```

I don't know how to implement it in my coding environment

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to return value like this.

```
function categoriesInConfirm()
{
    var cats = '';
    $('#newCategories li span').each(function (index,value){
        console.log($(this) + ' ,' + $(this).text());
        cats += $(this).text() +', ';
    });
    cats = cats.substring(0, cats.length - 2); // remove last , 
    return cats;
}
```